# Change default equals in goog.structs.Map

Tags: dictionary, equals, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am using Google Closure Tools. I am trying to store objects in a Map and I need to change the way that they are compared so that the keys will be evaluated as equal or unequal appropriately. Does anybody have clues as to how this can be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this can't be done at the present. I've rejiggered my code to use ints in the map instead!